# PineScript - How to compare a higher high to current price

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

Leveraging this script, I need to compare the current price to the most recent HH/HL/LH/LL and create labels for each difference. `if barstate.islast` need to compare the last bar state to the previous HH/HL/LH/LL and not sure how to access their value on the last execution of the script. What is the best way of creating a solution for this?

```
study(title="Pivot Points High Low (HH/HL/LH/LL) [Anan] ", shorttitle="Pivots HL [Anan]", overlay=true)

// - INPUTS
ShowPivots = input(true, title="Show Pivot Points")
ShowHHLL = input(true, title="Show HH,LL,LH,HL markers on Pivots Points")
left = input(5, minval=1, title="Pivot Length Left Hand Side")
right = input(5, minval=1, title="Pivot Length Right Hand Side")
ShowSRLevels = input(true, title="Show S/R Level Extensions")
maxLvlLen = input(0, minval=0, title="Maximum S/R Level Extension Length (0 = Max)")
ShowChannel = input(false, title="Show Levels as a Fractal Chaos Channel")
//
ShowFB = input(true, title="Show Fractal Break Alert Arrows")


// Determine pivots
pvtLenL = left
pvtLenR = right

// Get High and Low Pivot Points
pvthi_ = pivothigh(high, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)
pvtlo_ = pivotlow(low, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)

// Force Pivot completion before plotting.
pvthi = pvthi_
pvtlo = pvtlo_

//  ||-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------||
//  ||---   Higher Highs, Lower Highs, Higher Lows, Lower Lows  -------------------------------------------||
valuewhen_1 = valuewhen(pvthi, high[pvtLenR], 1)
valuewhen_2 = valuewhen(pvthi, high[pvtLenR], 0)
higherhigh = na(pvthi) ? na : valuewhen_1 < valuewhen_2 ? pvthi : na
valuewhen_3 = valuewhen(pvthi, high[pvtLenR], 1)
valuewhen_4 = valuewhen(pvthi, high[pvtLenR], 0)
lowerhigh = na(pvthi) ? na : valuewhen_3 > valuewhen_4 ? pvthi : na
valuewhen_5 = valuewhen(pvtlo, low[pvtLenR], 1)
valuewhen_6 = valuewhen(pvtlo, low[pvtLenR ], 0)
higherlow = na(pvtlo) ? na : valuewhen_5 < valuewhen_6 ? pvtlo : na
valuewhen_7 = valuewhen(pvtlo, low[pvtLenR], 1)
valuewhen_8 = valuewhen(pvtlo, low[pvtLenR ], 0)
lowerlow = na(pvtlo) ? na : valuewhen_7 > valuewhen_8 ? pvtlo : na


// If selected Display the HH/LL above/below candle.
plotshape(ShowHHLL ? higherhigh : na, title='HH', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green,50), text="HH", offset=-pvtLenR)
plotshape(ShowHHLL ? higherlow : na, title='HL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green,50), text="HL", offset=-pvtLenR)
plotshape(ShowHHLL ? lowerhigh : na, title='LH', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red,50), text="LH", offset=-pvtLenR)
plotshape(ShowHHLL ? lowerlow : na, title='LL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red,50), text="LL", offset=-pvtLenR)


plot(ShowPivots and not ShowHHLL ? pvthi : na, title='High Pivot', style=plot.style_circles, join=false, color=color.green, offset=-pvtLenR, linewidth=3)
plot(ShowPivots and not ShowHHLL ? pvtlo : na, title='Low Pivot', style=plot.style_circles, join=false, color=color.red, offset=-pvtLenR, linewidth=3)

//Count How many candles for current Pivot Level, If new reset.
counthi = 0
countlo = 0
counthi := na(pvthi) ? nz(counthi[1]) + 1 : 0
countlo := na(pvtlo) ? nz(countlo[1]) + 1 : 0

pvthis = 0.0
pvtlos = 0.0
pvthis := na(pvthi) ? pvthis[1] : high[pvtLenR]
pvtlos := na(pvtlo) ? pvtlos[1] : low[pvtLenR]

hipc = pvthis != pvthis[1] ? na : color.new(color.red,50)
lopc = pvtlos != pvtlos[1] ? na : color.new(color.green,50)

// Show Levels if Selected
plot(ShowSRLevels and not ShowChannel and (maxLvlLen == 0 or counthi < maxLvlLen) ? pvthis : na, color=hipc, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLenR , title="Top Levels",style=plot.style_circles)
plot(ShowSRLevels and not ShowChannel and (maxLvlLen == 0 or countlo < maxLvlLen) ? pvtlos : na, color=lopc, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLenR , title="Bottom Levels",style=plot.style_circles)

// Show Levels as a Fractal Chaos Channel
plot(ShowSRLevels and ShowChannel ? pvthis : na, color=color.green, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_stepline, offset=0, title="Top Chaos Channel", trackprice=false)
plot(ShowSRLevels and ShowChannel ? pvtlos : na, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_stepline, offset=0, title="Bottom Chaos Channel", trackprice=false)

// //
plotshape(ShowFB and buy?1:na, title="BUY Arrow", color=color.green, style=shape.labelup,location =location.belowbar)
plotshape(ShowFB and sell?-1:na, title="SELL Arrow", color=color.red, style=shape.labeldown,location =location.abovebar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `fixnan` function to continuously populate the variable with the last non null value.

```
float fixedHH = fixnan(higherhigh)

// add offset = -pvtLenR to move the plot to the left and match the HH points.
plot(fixedHH)
```

And then compare that var with the current price, calculate the difference etc.

```
bool lowerThanHH = close < fixedHH
float closeHHDiff = abs(fixedHH - close)
```

And finally pass the difference to the `label.new` function:

```
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high + 3*tr, tostring(closeHHDiff), xloc.bar_index, color = color.gray, style = label.style_label_down)
```

[image]

To not repeat the same code you can create a function and apply it to the HL, LL or LH as in the example above, but thats another question.

Comment: Thank you @e2e4 - how would you go about counting all of the HH's, HL's, LL's, and LH's plotted on the chart and store it in a variable?

Comment: Answered my own question - higherhighscount = ```higherhigh ? 1 : 0```
```higherhighstotal = sum(higherhighscount, lookbackPeriod)```